# Ignore/Skip default value on orderby menu_order?

Tags: wp-query

Is there a way to query all pages and order them by `menu_order` **but** ignore those pages that the default value of `0`?

I was trying to do something like this:

```
        $the_query = array( 
            'post_type' => self::POST_TYPE, 
            'posts_per_page' => $total, 
            'product_cat' => $product_category_name, 
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'suppress_filters' => '0' 
        );
```

Or do I need to create a filter to alter the `WP_Query`? any ideas?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following <s>(untested)</s> mini plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Support for ignoring the default menu order in WP_Query
 * Description: Uses the _ignore_default_menu_order argument
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193291/26350
 */
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where, $q )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if( (bool) $q->get( '_ignore_default_menu_order' ) ) {
        $where .= "AND {$wpdb->posts}.menu_order <> 0";
    }
    return $where;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Then you should be able to use the new custom query argument like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    [ 
        '_ignore_default_menu_order' => true,
    ]
);
```

to ignore posts with the default menu order (`0`).

You could also extend this to support any menu order as user input.

Comment: Thanks mate, this was a great start point to be able to finish it :)

Comment: This doesn't work because instead of removing the 'orderby menu_order' from the query, it inserts a 'where menu_order <> 0' and turns out to not display the posts intended too.

Comment: @CarlosOliveira The OP includes this part: *"Is there a way to query all pages and order them by menu_order but ignore those pages that the default value of 0?"* so I'm not sure what you mean by *"removing the 'orderby menu_order' from the query"*. It looks like you have another understanding of the original question than I do.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was influenced by my own problem, it is more related to this thread, in case you want to help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613024/remove-wp-posts-menu-order-from-select

Comment: @CarlosOliveira sure, no problem, it wouldn't though be the first time that I would misunderstand questions here on this stack ;-) If you've some unwanted ordering in the WP_Query, then a plugin or a theme is what comes first to mind. So I would make sure that's not the case.

Comment: for @CarlosOliveira use-case, i assume ... something like `IF(0 = wp_posts.menu_order, 999999, wp_posts.menu_order) AS menu_order` placed in the SELECT portion of the query would work

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked fine for me even with the custom ordering plugins also like 
[Intuitive CPO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts', 20, 1);

function custom_pre_get_posts($wp_query) {

    if(isset($wp_query->query['_ignore_default_menu_order']) && $wp_query->query['_ignore_default_menu_order']) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', $wp_query->query['orderby'] );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', $wp_query->query['order'] );
        unset($wp_query->query_vars['_ignore_default_menu_order']);
    }
}
```